# How can I view a PDF file via WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to view a PDF file by using a free toolkits or something that be an open source , and it must be supported Thai language (Unicode Character). Can anyone help me out !? I'm in a deep trouble now.

Comment: I think getting a framework for pdf display will work, use I-textSharp you can get it from nuget packages, else you can convert your pdf file to pictures and display them. That's what i did for mine.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use :

`<Window x:Class="PDFViewer1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Source="C:\User\Foo\Desktop\SomeFile.pdf" />
    </Grid>
</Window>`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no open source library for that. I've searched a while because I needed this functionality too.

The only "workaround" I've found is to use Ghostscript to convert your PDF into images which you can display, or you automate a free PDF viewer to print on the XPS Document writer and show the XPS. But in commercial products you have licence restrictions for boot workarounds.